# iPhone iOS 7 access LockScreen from App and show Text and Button for a Call

Tags: iphone, lockscreen, ios7.1

I'm developing an iPhone App. One Feature should be an PhoneCall-Button on the LockScreen and a Button to show some Information in a different view.

Is this possible without a Jailbreak?

If your answer is YES, how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible without a jailbreak.

Comment: Hmpf. What about showing a specific number as a missed call? The idea is to allocate a emergency number in the app, which could be called when Phone is locked. Or are there other possibilities?

Comment: Sorry, you can't modify the lock screen in any way. By saying lock, do you mean passcode lock?

Comment: Yes. After lookimg in AppStore, there are several Apps to show Infos on Lockscreen, but they seem to manipulate the backgroundImages to show information. But I want a phonecall-button or showing information in a different view per click on a button. Have a look at "contact lockscreen info" or "Lockscreen Pro".

Comment: Yes they must be static images. Sorry no legal way of doing what you need.